# Java Swing JTable TableModel setValueAt() not called when window closed

Tags: java, swing, jtable, focus, tablemodel

I have implemented a custom TableModel that gets data from a database and then saves data to the database when a cell is edited.

Ie:

```
AbstractTableModel myModel = new AbstractTableModel(){
    @Override public Object getValueAt(int r, int c){
        //get value from the database, return it
    }
    @Override public setValueAt(Object val, int r, int c){
        //update gui
        //save change in database
    }
    //other methods here....
}

JTable tbl = new JTable(myModel);
```

This works fine, however in order for setValueAt() to be called you need to stop editing the cell, by default this only occurs when you select another cell, press enter, etc.

I then added the line:

```
tbl.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", true);
```

This means when I click away from the table setValueAt() is called and the database is updated, however if I edit a cell's value, then close the JFrame without the table losing focus or clicking another cell setValueAt() is never called and so the database is not updated, therefore any change you have made to that cell is lost.

Is there any way to prevent this and make the setValueAt() function be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if JTable can do the trick, but you can handle window closing event, where manually accept new value of editing cell.

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        if(table.isEditing())
            // This will dispose editor and call setValueAt() of your model as normally happens
            table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
    }
});
```